# Author's first name in Greek is showing as a rectangle in references

Tags: bibliographies, greek

I'm really new with Tex and need to write a report in Greek. For my references (both in Greek and Latin characters) I use the APA style:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
...
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
```

After using Kile and XeLatex to produce the pdf file I get all my references in Latin characters correct. However the first name of the author in Greek is not displayed. Instead I get a rectangle...

Here is a sample .tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Didot}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[
top    = 2.75cm,
bottom = 2.50cm,
left   = 3.00cm,
right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\gr
\section{Εννοιολογικές διασαφηνίσεις}
Μπλα μπλα Μπλα \cite{Kap08} μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα       

\bibliographystyle{apacite} 
\bibliography{thesis} 

\end{document}
```

And here is thesis.bib with two references: one using Greek and one using Latin characters.

```
@book{Kap08,
year = 2008,
author = "Καπαχτσή, Β.", 
title = "Η αξιολόγηση του έργου του εκπαιδευτικού",
publisher = "{Αφοι Κυριακίδη Α.Ε.}",
address = "Αθήνα"
}

@Book{Hoy01,
Year = 2001,
Author = "Hoy, W. K., and Miske, C. G.",
Title = "Educational administration. Theory, research and practice         (6th ed.)",
Publisher = "{McGraw - Hill, Inc}",
Address = "New York"
}
```

[image]

I guess I must not be using properly the fonts packages, however everything I tried did not solve my problem.

Thank you in advance for your kind support!

Comment: You shouldn't use bibtex/apacite along with utf8 and xelatex. bibtex can't handle utf8 and funny things can happen. Use better biblatex and biber. Beside this don't use ucs + inputenc with xelatex.

Answer (score 1):

With `biblatex/biber`and a utf8-encoded .bib file, it compiles fine. I modified your code to adapt it to`biblatex`(-apa) and removed the files that are incompatible with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Didot}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{greekbiblio.bib}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{greek}{greek-apa}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[
top = 2.75cm,
bottom = 2.50cm,
left = 3.00cm,
right = 2.50cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\gr
\section{Εννοιολογικές διασαφηνίσεις}
Μπλα μπλα Μπλα \cite{Kap08} μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am really grateful for your answer and kind support. You have solved my problem!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the calls to `ucs` and `inputenc`, which only do damage with XeLaTeX. Also `xltxtra` is not needed and should be replaced by `fontspec`.

You can trick BibTeX into thinking that the initial is a capital beta with a workaround. However, sorting will be essentially arbitrary. It wouldn't matter only if the references are in order of appearance.

Here I use the `filecontents` environment just to make the example self-contained. Just fix your `thesis.bbl` file.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Kap08,
year = 2008,
author = "Καπαχτσή, {\relax Β}.", 
title = "Η αξιολόγηση του έργου του εκπαιδευτικού",
publisher = "{Αφοι Κυριακίδη Α.Ε.}",
address = "Αθήνα"
}

@Book{Hoy01,
Year = 2001,
Author = "Hoy, W. K., and Miske, C. G.",
Title = "Educational administration. Theory, research and practice         (6th ed.)",
Publisher = "{McGraw - Hill, Inc}",
Address = "New York"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xgreek}
\setmainfont{GFS Didot}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[greek, english]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage[
top    = 2.75cm,
bottom = 2.50cm,
left   = 3.00cm,
right  = 2.50cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\gr
\section{Εννοιολογικές διασαφηνίσεις}
Μπλα μπλα Μπλα \cite{Kap08} μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα μπλα Μπλα

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]